# Python pandas groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I have a `DataFrame df`, composed of `(age, height)`. I want to see how the mean of height changes with age, so I group `df` by `age` and try to form a new `DataFrame new_df`, composed of `(age, mean_height)`, code goes below:

```
groups = df.groupby('age')
new_df = groups.agg({'height' : np.mean,
                     'age' : # HOW to add age?})
```

but I don't know how to append `age` to `new_df`, hope anyone could give me some advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Age is the index of the aggregated dataframe:

```
In [95]: df = DataFrame({'age':[10,10,20,20,20], 'height':[140,150,145, 190,200]})

In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
   age  height
0   10     140
1   10     150
2   20     145
3   20     190
4   20     200

In [97]: groups = df.groupby('age')

In [98]: groups.agg({'height':np.mean})
Out[98]: 
         height
age            
10   145.000000
20   178.333333
```

And `df.groupby('age').mean()` would achieve the same result. If you want it as a column and not an index, add a call to `reset_index()`.

As an alternative, you can call the `groupby` with `as_index=False`:

```
groups = df.groupby('age', as_index=False)
groups.agg({'heigt': np.mean})
```